# Am i correctly using indexes for this mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

So i need some advice as to what i'm doing incorrectly.

My database is setup up exactly like a file system consisting of `folders` and `files`.
It begins with a folder, but can have a relatively infinite number of subfolders and or files.

```
{
   "name":"folder1",
   "uniqueID":"zzz0",
   "subcontents": [ {"name":"subfolder1", "uniqueID":"zzz1"}, 
                    {"name":"subfile1", "uniqueID":"zzz2"}, 
                    {"name":"subfile2", "uniqueID":"zzz3"}, 
                    {"name":"subfolder2", "subcontents": [...etc...], "uniqueID":"zzz4"}, 
                  ] 
}
```

Each folder/file document have a uniqueID so that I can reference to it (seen above zzz#).  My question is, can I make a mongoDB query to pull out only a single document?

Like say for example `db.fileSystemCollection.find({"uniqueID":"zzz4"})` and it would give me the following result? Do i have to use indexes to do this? I've been trying but the query returns empty every time.

intended result ---> {"name":"subfolder2", "subcontents": [...etc...], "uniqueID":"zzz4"}

**[EDIT]**
Based on the responses below, I will consider an XML database instead on mongoDB. The json structure cant be rearranged to work with MongoDB (too much data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; searching for `{uniqueID: "zzz4"}` will only get you documents whose top-level uniqueID matches.

What you probably want is to maintain an array on the document which lists all the unique IDs in that tree. So your document would be:

```
{
   "name":"folder1",
   "uniqueID":"zzz0",
   "idList": ["zzz0", "zzz1", "zzz2", "zzz3", "zzz4"],
   "subcontents": [ {"name":"subfolder1", "uniqueID":"zzz1"},
                    {"name":"subfile1", "uniqueID":"zzz2"},
                    {"name":"subfile2", "uniqueID":"zzz3"},
                    {"name":"subfolder2", "subcontents": [...etc...], "uniqueID":"zzz4"},
                  ]
}
```

Then you can index that:

```
db.fileSystemCollection.ensureIndex({"idList": 1})
```

Then you can find on it:

```
db.fileSystemCollection.find({"idList": "zzz4})
```

That'll return you those documents.

As an aside, if you're trying to store files in Mongo, have you looked at [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/)?

Comment: Hi Chris, will this implementation work with say id zzz900 ?  Assuming the it is contained within a child of a child of ...etc... a child of subfolder2 in the example above? So all I have to do is maintain the unique IDs in the idList at root level, it can find them?

Comment: Ok. so i just tested it. It does find the document, but it returns the whole root document and every thing. Is there no way to return just that single row containing the uniqueID ?

Comment: If it's at an arbitrary depth, no (at least not efficiently). If you know the depth in the tree, then sure.

Comment: The dept tree is unknown. Users can save their data at what ever dept they like, however they like. So i'm beginning to think Mongodb wont be the right job for this.. I'll Mark this answer as correct being "No it cant be done".. unless theres some other way?

Comment: If you can rearrange your data structures, then it's very doable. You could also do it with Mongo's map/reduce or aggregation framework in all likelyhood, but it's probably not going to to be as fast as you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is no, as it's stated by Chris.

Your embedded representation of a tree is really good for intuitive understanding (and implementation as well). But if you want to allow effective searches on your tree using indices in MongoDB, you might consider another ways for tree storage. A bunch of ways is listed at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

Please keep in mind that every representation has its own pros and cons depending on your access patterns.

Since for filesystem-like structure it's likely to have the ability to find all the sub contents of a given folder, you may use child references pattern for this:

```
{
   "name":"folder1",
   "uniqueID":"zzz0",
   "subcontents": [ "zzz1", 
                    "zzz2", 
                    "zzz3", 
                    "zzz4" 
                  ] 
}

{
  "name":"subfolder1", 
  "uniqueID":"zzz1"
}

...
```

Comment: +1 for the link of implementations. I will look through them and see what's right for the job. My limitation though is that i can't change the data's structure. The json files are already provided as is and would be a pain to modify that many.